# Reputation not being credited to SU account on some questions migrated from SF even though SF rep lost

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation

I've noticed that some questions that have been answered on ServerFault that eventually get migrated to SuperUser are not crediting me with the reputation that I gained on ServerFault, even though I lost the reputation on SF. An example is this question: "[As a bar owner, how can I block guest from using specific programs, like Spotify, over my free wifi?](https://superuser.com/questions/258455/as-a-bar-owner-how-can-i-block-guest-from-using-specific-programs-like-spotify/258458#258458)"

I gained 13 upvotes for my answer on ServerFault before the question was migrated. I gained another 4 upvotes on SuperUser. I recalc'ed my rep on SF so that I wouldn't have an inflated reputation and lost the 130 reputation points, however, never gained those 13 upvotes on SU. I have recalculated my reputation on SU with no difference.

Wouldn't make a big deal out of it except:

1. It could be a sign of bad things under the hood.
2. There are a few privs that I want on SU, but I am not a regular contributor so every little bit counts. =)

**EDIT:** After some more consultation, it seems that people are experiencing this on other sites as well. For example, migrations from Security to ServerFault. Perhaps this is a site-wide problem? Should this be moved to the Uber Meta?

**EDIT 2:** Apparently [as per this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64751/questions-about-the-gadgets-closure-migration), reputation is not migrated between sites. However, that simply has not been true at all times. I know for certain that at one point questions migrated from SF to SU caused me to lose the SF rep and gain the same amount of reputation on SU. For example, a question with 3 upvotes on SF would, when migrated, cost me 30 reps on SF and immediately gain 30 reputation points on SU even if no further upvotes on SU were gained for that question.

**EDIT 3:** I checked SU on April 5th 2011 and discovered that I had gained 200 points. My /reputation page shows that all reputation was gained on prior questions, and 180 points were gained from the question linked to in my first paragraph. Reputation appears to be migration now.

Comment: This also happened with me on: http://superuser.com/questions/243719

Comment: This does not need to be raised on Meta-opolis since the dev team sees across all child metas.

Comment: Your current reputation and votes on your posts suggests this was never the case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We recently fixed this bug, where migrated posts' upvotes didn't properly give reputation to the posts' owners, **if those owners existed on the destination site at the time of migration.**

We're working on fixing the bad reputation data. **By next week, your reputation will properly include these migrated votes.**

Comment: So this implies that a person *is* supposed to get the reputation points off of migrated questions? I seem to be getting conflicting information. It's all so confusing. =)

Comment: @WesleyDavid: there was some outdated information on [Jeff's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6378/do-migrated-questions-migrate-reputation-and-badges) - I've updated it.

Comment: Still a little unclear. Rep transfers over with the post or doesn't?

Comment: Thanks Jarod. Will you post an update somewhere when the bad data has been sent to its room without supper?

Comment: @random I'll edit my post to clarify.

Comment: Was this successfully fixed? I saw a small adjustment to my reps that didn't correspond to any upvotes, but only 30 points. I would have assumed more of an adjustment based on just that one question alone (mentioned in my original post).

Comment: It appears that the change has taken into effect. I just gained about 200 points all of a sudden.